# Static IP set on router or on computer

Tags: router, ip

I'm a bit confused as to how static IP's work. People talk about setting it up directly on the router, but you can also it up right on the computer. Do you need to do both? Or just one? If you were to just set the static IP on your computer, how would the router know which IP address to give that computer? I want to have my router give my server a static IP but continue to give the other computers IPs with DHCP .

Comment: This is a question about how to use DHCP which is an application layer protocol. Such questions are off-topic here, but are welcome on Super User.

Comment: NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professional managed networks. This question seems to be more related to computer configurations and applications (specifically DHCP) and how they function rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Comment: Nope... this is NE,,, as you can see by my answer we do not need DHCP to form a IP network... using static peers... ;-)

Comment: @ZEE, the non-DHCP part of your comment and answer is covered by the *"computer configurations"* part of my comment, which is coincidentally also off-topic. This is exactly why it was part of my off-topic message.

Comment: @ZEE, yes, this is NE, and configuration of end-user devices and application layer protocols are both off-topic on NE. Please, don't feed the bears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the router will give the ip to the server it is not a pure Static IP...
To have a pure Static IP you must define it in the Server/NIC... and then point the gateway to the router addres...

I think what you want is a feature that are present in some routers called "IP Reservation", where you associate a IP with a MAC Address from a NIC so the router always gave the same IP to that computer.